# Editing a timelapse in Photoshop and importing

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I’m making a timelapse in Photoshop, the problem is: I don’t want the final format to be GIF. Why not? Mainly because GIF is a lossy format and 256 colours is not enough.. I want to import it to another software and convert it to MP4, AVI, or similar. I’m searching for a software capable to do that but I didn’t have any luck with that so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can export video from Photoshop if you are using a timeline.

**File > Export > Render Video**

In there you have two rendering options:

- "Photoshop Image Sequence"
- **"Adobe Media Encoder"** (Select this and you will see all the options to create a video file)

Comment: I tried that...but for some reason photoshop start to not responding after i click on "interpret video" so i need to kil it on the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into products designed for slideshow creation where you can specify the time of each slide, transition time, transition effect if necessary. I will recommend what I am familiar with and point to Proshow Producer or Proshow Gold. There may be other alternatives but I am familiar with what I use. Although I do not make time lapse videos, it is eminently capable of doing that including handling music and various transition effect. Look at the following URL and get the trial version if you like:

http://www.photodex.com/

You can export in multiple formats and screen sizes from Proshow products.